# SwiftUI: Preventing binding value from passing back up?

Tags: swift, swiftui

in the `Secondary` struct, the `@Binding` property is `secondTime` and I want it to initially have the value from the "parent".
But when I change the value in this struct, the `time` property in the parent also changes.  Is there a way to get the value from the parent but prevent any changes to the value from going back up to the parent?

```
struct ContentView: View {
   
    @State var time: String = "";
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {

            Text("it is: \(time)")
            
            Secondary(secondTime: $time)
            
            Button("Change time") {
                time = "2 poclock"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
struct Secondary: View {
    @Binding var secondTime: String;
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("secondary time is \(secondTime)")
        
        Button("Change time again from Secondary View") {
            secondTime = "3 oclock"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The point of a Binding is to be two-way. State is what you want instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Secondary` use:

```
@State var secondTime: String
```

and in `ContentView` use:

```
Secondary(secondTime: time)
```

not `$time`

EDIT1:

If you want to click the button in `ContentView` to change both views,
but `Secondary` only changes itself, then try this approach:

```
struct Secondary: View {
    @Binding var secondTime: String
    @State var localTime: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Secondary time is \(localTime)")     // <--- here
            .onChange(of: secondTime) { newval in  // <--- here
                localTime = newval                 // <--- here
            }
        Button("Change time again from Secondary View") {
            localTime = "3 oclock " + String(Int.random(in: 1..<100)) // <-- to show changes
        }
    }
}
    
    struct ContentView: View {
        @State var time: String = ""
        
        var body: some View {
            VStack (spacing: 55) {
                Text("ContentView it is: \(time)")
                Secondary(secondTime: $time)
                Button("Change time") {
                    time = "2 oclock " + String(Int.random(in: 1..<100))  // <-- to show changes
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't get the value back from the parent though, right?

Comment: that's right. The question was "... is there a way to get the value from the parent but prevent any changes to the value from going back up to the parent"

Comment: Yeah it could just be an ambiguous misunderstanding on my part, because I inferred it that when you click the button in `ContentView` it changes both, but `Secondary` only changes itself.

Comment: This is easy to do as well. Is this what `arfanGhali2` wants to do?

Comment: Not sure tbh. Doesn’t harm to do both just in case, or just ask for clarification I guess